# How to create a select button on TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE and i don't know how i can create un select button on the toolbar ?

For example, look at this demo : http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

I want to create buttons like "Styles", "Paragraph", "Font Family" etc...

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks !

Edit : I know how to create a plugin with a basic button.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far, then people may be able to make suggestions.

Comment: Yes.... But not good answers^^

Comment: creating complex buttons for the tinymce toolbar is a bit...tricky. i will need some time to create an example

Comment: I know how to create un new button, a new plugin, but a select directly on toolbar... ??!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to create an own example but found out moxiecode made one already.
Here it is: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/listbox_splitbutton.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to install plugins or if those buttons are part of standard functionality then you need to modify your tinyMCE configuration.
On your link there is possibility to view source of that example. If you do that then you can see that there are used `theme_advanced_buttons*` settings to add buttons.
To get what you want you should use
`theme_advanced_buttons1 : "styleselect,formatselect,fontselect"`
in tinyMCE init configuration.